# Play sounds in Ionic React with Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, audio, mobile, capacitor

I am building a simple app using Ionic React and Capacitor. I am trying to run a sound when a button was clicked. Can anybody tell me which is the right way to do things like this?
I searched on the Ionic forum and also on google and seems that only angular project support audio or provide a framework for that.

Comment: You can play audio in Ionic just using Javascript. You don't need a library. Example: var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();

Comment: @slashsharp that does not work for mobile apps.

Comment: I've published an app where audio is one of the main feature of the apps and it works fine. What do you mean it doesn't work for mobile apps?

Answer (score 1):

There's a capacitor plugin that plays audio and it works great!: [@capacitor-community/native-audio](https://github.com/capacitor-community/native-audio)

Comment: Maybe a final answer to this question would be to compare @capacitor-community/native-audio and HTMLAudioElement and say which one is better for which use, case, advantages etc.? 

For this reason, I consider this question as requiring more details still (unanswered).